# cassandra insert json character ' error

Tags: json, insert, cassandra, character

I'm trying to insert some values in json format in cassandra but as the character  apostrophe (') is the one for limit json string I cannot insert phrases like "I'm" or "let's go"

do you know an alternative to be able of insert this kind of messages using json format?

**Statement:**

```
INSERT INTO TweetsTest JSON '{"IsFavorited":false,"ProfileLocation":"Paris, TX","IsPossiblySensitive":false,"User":"abela_here","Message":"biebahpurpose: https:\/\/t.co\/e5csn7ZNrl RT halsey: **Let's** go. #TheFeeling justinbieber Skrillex","CreatedAt":"Wed Oct 28 00:33:22 CST 2015","IsRetweet":false,"IsRetweeted":false,"IsTruncated":false,"QuotedStatusId":-1,"RetweetCount":0,"InReplyToScreenName":null,"Source":"<a href=\"http:\/\/ifttt.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">IFTTT<\/a>","InReplyToUserId":-1,"UserId":3301301628,"Id":659256625686016000,"CurrentUserRetweetId":-1,"HashtagEntities":"TheFeeling"}';
```

**ERROR:**

Invalid syntax at line 1, char 204
  INSERT INTO TweetsTest JSON '{"IsFavorited":false,"ProfileLocation":"Paris, TX","IsPossiblySensitive":false,"User":"abela_here","Message":"biebahpurpose: https://t.co/e5csn7ZNrl RT halsey: Let\'s go. #TheFeeling justinbieber Skrillex","CreatedAt":"Wed Oct 28 00:33:22 CST 2015","IsRetweet":false,"IsRetweeted":false,"IsTruncated":false,"QuotedStatusId":-1,"RetweetCount":0,"InReplyToScreenName":null,"Source":"IFTTT</a>","InReplyToUserId":-1,"UserId":3301301628,"Id":659256625686016000,"CurrentUserRetweetId":-1,"HashtagEntities":"TheFeeling"}';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escape character in CQL is the single quote ('). So you need to write two apostrophe's ('') whenever you want to insert one ('). This is the same when inserting as JSON.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/escape_char_r.html